# Updating location in the background does not keep app running after being backgrounded

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

I'm almost done making a location-based navigating app. It plays a sound upon receiving alerts, and also it should stay open in the background upon going to Google Maps so that, after travelling for a long distance or time, they can come back to the app and pick things up where they left off. However, this does not work, even though I've got `Location Usage` and `Location Always Usage` defined and requested. Upon going into the background, I can see in the Xcode debugger that some specified JSON from the server is received, but the sound will not play. Also, if the user is gone for long enough, even while coordinates are being printed out in the console from `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`, then the app will end and kick the user back out to the initial view controller. How can I stop that? I've seen other apps stay open in the background and get a blue status bar in iOS saying that "[this app] is using your location". If I can't get my app to stay open for more than 180 seconds, then how can I save that current data so that the user can resume where he/she left off?

```
var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
    mapView.delegate = self

    if let userLocation = mapView.userLocation.location { // because sometimes there is no coordinate and it will unwrap nil.
        mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.coordinate
        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 9484.1, 9484.1)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }

    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didUpdate: MKUserLocation) {
    let userLocation = mapView.userLocation
    mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location!.coordinate
    //let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(frontedUserLocation, 1855, 1855)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(mapView.centerCoordinate, 9484.1, 9484.1)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let mostRecentLocation = locations.last else {
        return
    }

    // Add another annotation to the map.
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    annotation.coordinate = mostRecentLocation.coordinate

    // Also add to our map so we can remove old values later

    // Remove values if the array is too big

    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {

    } else {
        print("App is backgrounded. New location is %@", mostRecentLocation)
        print("Background time remaining = \(UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining) seconds")
        if (UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining < 175.2) {
            print("Time low. Re-registering...")
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            self.registerBackgroundTask()
        }
    }
}

/*func operate() {
    //call endBackgroundTask() on completion..
    switch UIApplication.shared.applicationState {
    case .active:
        print("App is active.")
    case .background:
        print("App is in background.")
        print("Background time remaining = \(UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining) seconds")
        if (UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining < 175.2) {
            print("Time low. Re-registering...")
            self.registerBackgroundTask()
        }
    case .inactive:
        endBackgroundTask()
        self.registerBackgroundTask()
        break
    }
}*/

func updateCoords() {
    let updateCoordinates = CloudOperation() // edit this to accept a different parameter
    let userLocation = self.mapView.userLocation.location!.coordinate
    updateCoordinates.latit = userLocation.latitude
    updateCoordinates.longi = userLocation.longitude
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    /*backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask { [weak self] in
        self?.endBackgroundTask()
    }
    assert(backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)*/

    //self.registerBackgroundTask()
    print("Trying to update...")

    dump(self.phase)
}
```

Thanks!

[image: Capabilities]
[image: Capabilities 2]

Comment: You need to show the code where you set up your Location manager

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you have activated background mode in your `CLLocationManager`:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
```

Comment: This works on an iPhone 7, but not on iOS 10 on an iPhone 6s.